# All .NET Referenced dll into the project's dll

Tags: .net, dll, .net-assembly

I have a project that references two other dlls.
After compiling this project I want to pass the project's dll over, to another developers.

I don't want to pass them all the referenced dll too.
I want all the referenced dll to be inside the single project's dll.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is there any other way doing so? Any VS build-in option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by merging them into a single assembly. This can be done by using ILMerge which can be downloaded here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630

There exists a detailled documentation which is available here: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.doc

Comment: Is there any other way doing so? Is there any VS build-in option?

Comment: You could of course programatically generate the assembly which is much more complicated...

Answer (score 1):

Fody [Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) is probably easier (and safer) to integrate (it simply embeds the referenced dlls into yours as resources, and extracts them when needed).

Pro: it supports native assemblies, which ILMerge does not.

Note than if you prefer the ILMerge way (aka IL manipulation which completely removes the original assemblies), [ILRepack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack) is an open-source clone, with more functionalities (e.g. WPF support).